# Issue in launching the Sikuli setup

Tags: java, windows, automation, sikuli

I came to know about Sikuli recently, so I thought of integrating that with my selenium project because it identifies objects using Images/Screenshot's. And it will make my work easier. However, when I tried to execute the `runSetup` command in windows i'm getting the below error

[image]

Steps I have followed, to execute Sikuli:

1. Download the sikuli setup jar from [here](https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download)
2. Double Click on `sikuli-setup JAR`, and you get `runSetup` command. Execute the `runSetup` command. And I'm facing this error. Does anyone have an idea to solve the issue?

JDK Version - 1.8. I am trying to install on a windows 7, 64 bit machine

Comment: Try to run the installation with admin permissions.

Comment: @EugeneS - Now I can be able to install.Thanks..And one quick question. I tried integrating sikuli wiith selenium. And I tried a simple login app. I can be able to execute scripts via sikuli. Typing through sikuli in the user name field, But sometimes, mouse is not hovered to the username field, so my test scripts failed. And it is an intermittent behaviour. Not sure why this happens. And your thought's on this?

Comment: Glad that helped. I added a full answer below so you can accept it. In regards to your other inquiry, please post it as a new question and paste a link here in comments with my name reference so I will see it.

Comment: @EugeneS - As discussed, provided I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859753/intermittent-failure-of-sikuli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some known situations when Sikuli requires admin rights. Installation process might be one of them as it accessing the internet and writing files on disk. Try to run the installation as admin and see if that makes a difference for you. Assuming you are in Windows and run the setup from command line, just start the cmd as admin. Once you run cmd as admin, all the subsequent commands will have admin privileges.